# Problem with sets using $n$-balls in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus

How can I prove if this subset is open, closed or neither?

$$S \subset \mathbb{R}^2, \quad S=[1,2] \times [1,2]$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can show that $[1, 2]$ is closed, then it is straightforward to show that in a metric space $M$, the Cartesian product of two closed subsets is itself a closed subset of $M \times M$.

First show that $[1, 2]$ is closed by showing it contains all its limits. Then suppose that $A \subset M$ is closed, where $M$ is a metric space. Let $p \in M \times M$ be the limit of a sequence $(p_n)$ where for each $n$, $p_n \in A \times A$. Show that $p \in A \times A$. Finally, conclude that $S$ is closed.

Answer (score 0):

$[1,2]$ is a closed interval, so $[1,2]\times[1,2]$ is also closed under product topology.

$[1,2]$ is closed because $\mathbb{R}\setminus[1,2]$ is open by ball test.